# Query based on RealmList as member variable

Tags: android, realm

How can we query Realm Database based on the RealmList as the member variable?

Let me further clarify the use case.

I have the following class:

```
public class Match extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Expose
    private String matchid;

    @Expose
    private RealmList<Team> Team = new RealmList<>();
}
```

And Team object looks like this:

```
public class Team extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Expose
    private String teamid;
}
```

I want to query all Match Objects in which `teamid` is 1 for example.

Is it possible? How can we write such query in Realm?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The examples seem to clearly show `realm.where(Team.class).equalTo("teamid", 1)`

Comment: For more details, https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries

Comment: But that will query all Team objects.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. I don't think you can query the Match objects where the `teamId` is 1. You would need to either instead have a Match object that only held team 1, or have the Team hold a reference to the Matches that it corresponds to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RealmResults<Match> results = realm.where(Match.class)
                                   .equalTo("Team.teamid", 1).findAll();
```

More info on link queries: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries